# Do you "convert money" when you are exchanging with a foreign currency?

Tags: word-usage, terminology, finance

I was in the bank the other day and the teller asked me how much of my money I wanted to "convert" into USD.

Is this the right form of usage? Cambridge dictionary [defines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/convert) convert in many ways but all of them somewhat relate to a change of essence of whatever is being converted.

However, I think my money is not changing its essence, I'm just exchanging with money in another currency which is arguably similar buying milk from the grocery store. (Exchanging money vs money or money vs good)

Comment: _Exchange_ seems more natural to me, but in the context _convert_, I think, is common as well.

Comment: "Convert" is certainly a common verb to use, when referring to exchanging money.  I've no idea what terms are "approved" by banks and international monetary organizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/convert) does list this definition of **convert**:

> Change (money, stocks, or units in which a quantity is expressed) into others of a different kind.

Example sentence:

> ‘A weak foreign currency reduces the amount of money investors receive when the foreign currency is **converted**.’

Attribution: "Convert | Definition of Convert in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed May 28, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/convert.